# jquery autocomplete array help

Tags: jquery, arrays, autocomplete

Hey all i am trying to use my already array that i populated into the jQuery Source:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#partSearchBox").autocomplete({
        source: [partNum]
    });
});
```

the partNum looks like this:

```
gh3423645,jh324332,iu45233,gk324456, etc etc...
```

And i can get to each data by doing this:

```
partNum[0] or partNum[3], etc...
```

How can i already use that array within the source? The code i posted above has no suggestions once i start typing?

Thanks!

David

Comment: is parnNum an array? it makes source an array of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `partNum` is already an array, try using

```
source: partNum
```

instead of `source: [partNum]`.

Comment: Gerrr.. i knew i was over thinking it! Thanks Emmett! :o)